# Looking for a Docker expert, dealing with issues to import data from Python into MSSQL

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04, pyodbc

I have tried almost every blog in order to resolve this but nothing is working.

**Error Message**: pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

**Below is the Dockerfile I am having**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \      
    apt-get install -y \    
    libpq-dev \     
    gcc \
    python3-pip \
    unixodbc-dev

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl apt-utils apt-transport-https debconf-utils gcc build-essential g++-5\
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated msodbcsql17

RUN pip3 install pyodbc

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt


RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "test.py" ]
```

**Below is the requirements file I am having**

```
pyodbc==4.0.30
psycopg2-binary
sqlparams
pandas
xlrd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if you are trying to connect your local host dB instance from the container. If that is correct, then please use the IP address instead of localhost, it should work.

**UPDATE**: Below is the changes that I made.

1. I replace **pyodbc** library with **pymssql**
2. Within the Server Name instead of the hostname, I added the **IP address** of my machine.

Comment: Sure. Let me try. Would get back.